# View gets pushed down when performing segue with a visible navigation bar

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar, uistoryboard

I'm performing a segue with a navigation bar over a view that has the navigation bar hidden, when the segue starts my current view seems to get pushed down by the navigation bar that is not hidden in my segue… which looks bad…

If I remove the `setNavigationBarHidden:animated` method I don't see a navigation bar after performing the segue, and the issue doesn't manifest anymore.

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mailSignUp" sender:nil];
    } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"logIn" sender:nil];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide your navigation bar you have to do it in the root controller, the first controller in your app. 
My guess is that you have had setup a modal segue in interface builder from a certain button to the following view. By doing so you have the following view sliding in from down to top. 
I'm also guessing you are using the lastest xcode version [4.5.2] and running it on ios6.

Try deleting your segue from interface builder. Also, instead of your:

> [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mailSignUp" sender:nil];

use:

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

YourSecondController *secondController = (YourSecondController *)[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourSecondController"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:yourSecondController animated:YES];
```

[substitue YourSecondController with mailSignUp or whatever controller you want to perform segue to]

Also, if you want to hide your navigation bar you have to add this line of code in your (void)viewdidload method in your root controller.

If you run your segue programmatically like this, you should achieve your second view slide from right to left. Let me know if this helped or provide more info if it is not sufficient or exact.

Comment: Also, in interface builder, be sure to set your 'Storyboard Id' to 'YourSecondController' or your'll get an error.